# How to make a circle outside of an input type color that has a circle form with CSS?

Tags: css

I already did a circle with my input of `type color` I need that circle to be inside of another one, I already tried out with some things but doesn't work with an input, I would like to know how can I do that?

The circle its actually inside of the other one the thing it's you can't actually see it, how can I solve this?

This is how it should looks like: https://www.screencast.com/t/0Xw9Sv4NDgqT

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    
    <title>Colour picker</title>
    <style>
       input[type="color"] {
            opacity: 0;
            display: block;
            width: 22px;
            height: 22px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50% !important;
            position: relative;
        }
        #color-picker-wrapper {
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
            border-radius: 50% !important;
            position: relative;
        }
        .pick-color{
            font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #A2A2A2 ;
        }
        .outer {
            background-color:white;
            width:2rem; /* You can define it by % also */
            height:2rem; /* You can define it by % also */
            position:relative;
            border:2px solid #A2A2A2 ;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .inner {
            top: 25%; left:25%; /* of the container */
            width:50%; /* of the container */
            height:50%; /* of the container */
            
            border:1px solid black;
            border-radius: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="text" id="hex">
        <input type="color" id="color">
    </div>-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
            <p class="mr-2 pick-color"><strong>Pick a color</strong></p>
            <div id="color-picker-wrapper">
                <input type="color"  id="color-picker">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer circle shapeborder">
            <input type="color"  class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>  
<!--This is for testing, this change the background of the body and set the color HEX to the input-->
<script>
    /*let inputColor = document.querySelector('#color');
    let inputHex = document.querySelector('#hex');
    let borderColor = document.getElementById('color');
    let colorWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    colorWrapper.style.backgroundColor =  borderColor.value;
    inputColor.addEventListener('input', () => {
        let color = inputColor.value;
        inputHex.value = color;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });*/
    var color_picker = document.getElementById("color-picker");
    var color_picker_wrapper = document.getElementById("color-picker-wrapper");
    color_picker.onchange = function() {
        color_picker_wrapper.style.backgroundColor = color_picker.value;    
    }
    color_picker_wrapper.style.backgroundColor = color_picker.value;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. You have two circular color inputs. What exactly do you want to have happen?

Comment: @symlink I have a circular input of type colour that has to be inside of another circle that's what I want it should look like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/0Xw9Sv4NDgqT

Comment: So when a color is selected in that white circle, the circle is filled with a smaller circle of the color picked?

Comment: Yes, it should always be filled with the smaller circle either if you select the colour or not, the thing is that t's not showing the small circle with the colour @symlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that you will have:

- An outermost `div` (`#color-picker-container`): responsible for the outer border.
- An inner `div` (`#color-picker-wrapper`) a little bit smaller: responsible for presenting the picked color.
- An innermost `input` (`#color-picker`): set `opacity:0` to be hidden away

```js
const color_picker = document.getElementById("color-picker");
const color_picker_wrapper = document.getElementById("color-picker-wrapper");

color_picker.onchange = function() {
  color_picker_wrapper.style.backgroundColor = color_picker.value;
}
  
color_picker_wrapper.style.backgroundColor = color_picker.value;
```

```css
input[type="color"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
    
#color-picker-container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #A2A2A2;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
    
#color-picker-wrapper {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.pick-color {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #A2A2A2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Our css -->

  <title>Colour picker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
      <p class="mr-2 pick-color"><strong>Pick a color</strong></p>
      <div id="color-picker-container">
        <div id="color-picker-wrapper">
          <input type="color" id="color-picker">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```